# Netty 4.0 & Applet

Tags: java, applet, netty

Applet freezes when I use **Netty 4.0**. If I use the **Netty 3**, the Applet starts correctly. My code is very simple, and I can not understand where the mistake.

```
public class Applet extends JApplet
{
        @Override
    public void init()
    {   
            try {
                new DiscardServer(1020).run();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Applet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class DiscardServer {
    private final int port;
    public DiscardServer(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }
    public void run() throws Exception {
        ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
        try {
            b.group(new NioEventLoopGroup(), new NioEventLoopGroup()).channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class).localAddress(port)
             .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                @Override
                public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                    ch.pipeline().addLast(new DiscardServerHandler());
                }
             });
            ChannelFuture f = b.bind().sync();
            f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
        } finally {
            b.shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class DiscardServerHandler extends ChannelInboundByteHandlerAdapter {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DiscardServerHandler.class.getName());
    @Override
    public void inboundBufferUpdated(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf in) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Message " + new String(in.array()));
        in.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) throws Exception {
        logger.log(Level.WARNING,"Unexpected exception from downstream.",cause);
        ctx.close();
    }
}
```

Last post in the console:

```
network: Cache entry not found [url: file:/D:/java/Applet/dist/lib/netty-4.0.0.Alpha6-20121021.180934-2.jar, version: null]
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.getPermissions CeilingPolicy allPerms
```

If I remove the line:

```
ChannelFuture f = b.bind().sync();
```

, the applet starts, but the DiscardServer is not working.